# Stay in the current tab after delete a record in cakephp using ajax

Tags: ajax, cakephp

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'useroccupations', 'action' => 'savedJobDelete')); ?>'",
            data: ({type:'original'}),
            success: function (data){
                $('#menu1').tab('show');
            }
        });
```

Here is my ajax and It's not working correctly . Can I get best advice form you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   dataType: "json",
   type: "POST",
   url: "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'useroccupations', 'action' => 'savedJobDelete')); ?>",
   data: ({type:'original'}),
   success: function (data){
       $('#menu1').tab('show');
   }
});
```

What I did is removing extra single quote in url `savedJobDelete')); ?>'",`

Comment: If this is not the error, Please describe what is not working properly